# Entity Framework / LINQ / .NET - Perform 'LIKE' on Date

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

Is there a way to Perform 'LIKE' on Date using LINQ / .NET?  I'm trying to do to a autocomplete box allowing users to look for times.

```
        Function GetTimesAvailable(term As String) As ActionResult
        Using db As New Context
            Dim vals = db.CalendarSlots.Where(Function(c) c.TimeStart.ToString.Contains(term)).Select(Function(c) c.TimeStart).ToList
            Return Json(vals, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
        End Using

    End Function
```

This code doesn't work:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do this? Dates are ordinal types, you would have a much easier time coding *and* end up with much more efficient queries if you just used ranges.

Comment: I want it because this is what the sales team wants on the page.  I checked the spec efficient queries are not required. They also do not want ranges.

Comment: Uh, you don't ask the sales people that, because they have no clue what they're talking about. We're talking about exactly the same outcome here, just without the horrible kludge. They don't need to *enter* a range, but *you* still use ranged queries for the autocomplete. And no offense, but the phrase "efficient queries are not required" is one of the most unprofessional statements I have ever heard.

Comment: Could you please add an example to do a ranged query like your suggesting?  I honestly have no clue how to make a ranged query look like an autocomplete.  I'm not offended by your statement but I am bothered you seem to be indicating that you have a solution that your not sharing.

Comment: On a side note, VB.NET actually has a `Like` operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<Extension>
Private Function ContainsSplit(source As String, toCheck As String, comp As StringComparison)
    Dim sp = toCheck.Split(" ")

    For Each s In sp
        If source.IndexOf(s, comp) < 0 Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next

    Return True
End Function

<Extension>
Public Function GetTimesAvailable(ByVal Context As Context, term As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Using db As New Context
        Dim query1 = From c In db.CalendarSlots
                     Group c By c.TimeStart Into TimeStartGroup = Count()
                    Select TimeStart

        Dim times = query1.ToList

        Dim timesAsString = From t In times
                            Select TimeStart = t.ToLongDateString & " " & t.ToLongTimeString

        Dim times2 = timesAsString.ToList

        Dim query2 = From t In times2
                Where t.ContainsSplit(term, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                Select t
        Return query2.ToList
    End Using
End Function
```

I was hoping there would be a way of dong the contains on the server side.  The only way I can think of is to materialize the query with .toList and then do the contains.

Comment: Is this the answer? You haven't provided any actual text.

Comment: @Gabe - He's not going to answer you, he doesn't have an account on SO, It was migrated from Programmers.SE

Comment: It's a answer.  I was hoping for a better answer that can do the same thing but could filter the data before materializing it.